# How to use Azure kudu zipdeploy from a Bamboo deployment server

Tags: powershell, azure, bamboo, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to find a way to deploy an app service update to an Azure app service from a Bamboo deployment server script task using PowerShell.

I am running into a problem with the authentication part.

Note: Credit to https://markheath.net/post/deploy-azure-webapp-kudu-zip-api for the script ideas.

Below is my PowerShell script.

```
$PublishingUsername = ["The value of the userName property name in the Azure PublishSettings file"]

$PublishingPassword = ["The value of the userPWD property name in the Azure PublishSettings file"]

$SlotName = ["The name of the slot. I.e. qa"]

$WebAppName = ["The name of the app service in Azure"]

$LocalPath = ["The location of zip file that holds the VS2017 Publish Output files"]

function Upload-ZipDeploy() {

    $pair = "$($PublishingUsername):$($PublishingPassword)"
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = $basicAuthValue
    }

    if ($SlotName -eq ""){
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
    }
    else{
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$WebAppName`-$SlotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
    }

    # use kudu deploy from zip file
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers $Headers `
        -InFile $LocalPath -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Method Post


}

Upload-ZipDeploy
```

When I run this script I get

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Server Error
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the 
credentials that you supplied.
```

I am using the userName and userPWD values from the *.PublishSettings file I downloaded for the app service deployment slot settings in Azure. I can import this same *.PublishSettings file in the publish wizard in VS2017 and successfully publish to that slot. I just can't seem to do it in PowerShell.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The solution here was fairly simple. I was using the Microsoft generated username from the publishSettings file and that username started with a $. So, PowerShell was stripping the $and first characters. I prefixed the username with a back-tick and this prevented the username from being stripped. It is now working correctly.

I also added the:443 after the azurewebsites.net domain since that is the way it appears in the publishSettings file, but I am not sure it is actually needed since the url starts with https:// already.

Comment: You don't need the trailing port number. You can also make an authenticated call against Kudu by passing Basic auth credentials straight into the URL: `https://\`$WebAppName:\`$PublishingPassword@site.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy`