# Publishing to Azure via Kudu ZipDeploy using powershell causes a 401 when I try to access the API afterward

Tags: powershell, azure, bamboo, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1.4 project and I can deploy this from within Visual Studio 2017 15.5.7 using the Publish menu item and Deploy to Azure type. This has been working just fine.

I am working on trying to deploy this project using a Bamboo Build/Deployment server and I have gotten my powershell script to upload the published files in a zip file to the Kudu Zipdeploy REST endpoint and I can see the deployment now in the Kudu list of deployments. This was worked out in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968029/azure-project-kudu-accepts-uploaded-zip-file-to-the-zipdeploy-endpoint-but-does) with the help of David Ebbo.

However, now, when I try to access the API using Postman after using this powershell Kudu deployment method I get a 401 unauthorized status.

Publishing the exact same build using the VS2017 publish menu method allows me to access the API just fine so there is something still incorrect about my Kudu publish via Bamboo deployment and Powershell.

Here is my Powershell function;

```
Function Upload-ZipDeploy() {

    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $PublishingUsername, $publishingPassword)))
    $userAgent = "powershell/1.0"
    if(!$SlotName) 
    {
        $apiUrl = "https://$WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
    }
    else {
        $apiUrl = "https://$WebAppName-$SlotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
    }

    $filePath = $LocalPath
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

}
```

I read a MS forum post talking about the zip endpoint and getting a 401 error after deployment where they solved it by putting a trailing / on the deployment URL. I tried that with my script but it did not make any difference.

Here is a snippet from the log stream showing that the deployment was successful;

```
2018-04-27T13:34:37    Finished successfully.    
2018-04-27T13:34:37  Running post deployment command(s)...
2018-04-27T13:34:37  Deployment successful.
2018-04-27 13:34:37.160 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:13601/iisintegration  0
2018-04-27 13:34:37.177 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 16.935ms 202
```

However, when I try to hit one of my API endpoints after this Kudu deployment, I get a 401 Unauthorized status.

When looking at the Log Stream for the API in Azure, I see the following;

```
018-04-27 13:37:32.814 +00:00 [Critical] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting startup assembly exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup failed to execute. See the 
inner exception for more details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String 
codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, 
StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean 
 throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean 
suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at 
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName 
assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, 
StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean 
throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices
(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

At this point, I am stuck. What am I missing here?

**EDIT #1 4/30/18**

I added the site extensions as suggested by David Ebbo. I am no longer getting the file not found error in the Azure log stream but I am still getting the 401 Unauthorized error when I try to access my API endpoints after a deployment using Kupu ZipDeploy. Again, I do not get this error and everything works fine if I deploy using VS2017 publish.

Here is my Azure extensions screenshot on my portal.

[Azure Portal Site Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5mOy.png)

**EDIT #2 - 4/30/18**

OK, I believe that the issue is specifically related to the multi-target frameworks. I removed the projects from the solution that needed the multi-target setup and now I can deploy using ZipDeploy in Bamboo and I no longer get the 401 Unauthorized status when accessing the endpoints. I believe I can work with this option as the projects they were multi-targeted do not actually need to be deployed to Azure since they were DB related utilities and I can run them from a local server that targets the Azure database.

Comment: First step is to identify if it's a [deployment or runtime issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues)

Comment: It has to be a deployment issue, right? If I can publish using the VS2017 Publish menu method with no problems but get the 401 Unauthorised and the related Logstream errors when I publish using the powershell script in Bamboo deploy.

Comment: The key question here is: does zipdeploy work correctly? i.e. **are the files deployed under your wwwroot folder identical to what's in your zip file**. If so, then zipdeploy did exactly the right thing and deployed your files. If it doesn't work, it is likely due to the **content** of your zip being incorrect. If so, your question should be completely different and not involve zipdeploy at all, since it is not relevant. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will check this and post back the result.

Comment: Ok. I compared the files in Kudu wwwroot that I published using VS2017  publish method, while the API is currently working properly on Azure, to the files in my zip deployment package. Both have the exact same 115 files. If I then push out that zip file using the powershell script listed in my OP, the API then starts giving me the 401 unauthorized with every request.

Comment: The Azure logstream is saying   
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup is not a file from my project or even listed in wwwroot on Azure when the API is working properly.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure I follow. When using zipdeploy, did you determine whether the content of wwwroot matches the content of your zip? There should be no VS2017 in the equation at all when doing this test, which is why your comment confuses me.

Comment: Yes. The contents of wwwroot matched the contents of my zipdeploy zip  file after running the zipdeploy script. I was only mentioning VS2017 because it works when using VS2017 publish so I also compared the contents of my zipdeploy zip file to what VS2017 put in Azure wwwroot to see if I was missing something in my zipdeploy zip file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. That takes zipdeploy completely out of the equation, which was my angle here. So I'll stay of of this one :) But you may want to reword the question as more of a .NET Core question, since we now know it is not related to Kudu/zipdeploy.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how it takes the zip deploy (or perhaps Kudu) out of the problem domain since the issue occurs when we use zipdeploy as opposed to VS2107 publish. Are you suggesting that perhaps VS2017 publish is adding something because I have Azure services support integrated in VS2017 and those files do not get incorporated into an Azure deployment done outside of VS2017, such as the Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup that is not being found when I do a Zipdeploy based deployment outside of VS2017?

Comment: zipdeploy's only job is to take your zip, and correctly deploy its content (which we established it did). If that ends up not working at runtime, it's likely that the content of your zip is wrong, and that makes zipdeploy irrelevant. e.g. you'd see the same behavior if you deployed the exact same files via FTP. Bottom line: you need to focus on understanding why the content of your zip does not run.

Comment: The files in my zip deploy zip file are exactly the same as the files that get put in  the Azure wwwroot folder when I run VS2017 publish, which works. If zip deploy is only responsible for putting the files in wwwroot, I will concede  that it is probably not actually the zip deploy endpoint but possibly something that VS2017 is adding to it's publish process that isn't getting added or triggered during the zip Kudu deployment process that is triggered by the zip deploy upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may know what your problem is, and it is not directly related to zipdeploy. Unlike the older Core runtimes, 2.1 is not installed on the VM (because it's preview). Instead, you need to install a site extension into your Web App. See [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-using-asp-net-core-previews-on-azure-app-service/) for details (page was written for Preview 1, but it's the same deal for Preview 2).

I tried this using a clean Web App, default new Core 2.1 Preview 2 in VS, and zip deploy. And it ran fine after installing the site extension.

Comment: I tried adding ASP.NET Core 2.1 (x86) Runtime extensions on my Azure portal QA deployment slot as well as the Main web app and then ran the deployment script pushing my files to Kudu zipdeploy. I no longer got the error about the missing file in the log stream but it is still getting a 401 unauthorized when I try to access an API endpoint. Again, I do not get that error if I deploy using VS2017 publish. I also tried using the ASP.NET Core 2.1 (x64) Runtime but it made no difference.

Comment: I added an edit to my OP and included a screenshot of the site extensions list from my portal

Comment: One thing that may pertain is that my primary API is using <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework> but my support class libraries are multi-targeted, using <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>. I don't know if that is relevant or not.

Comment: David, it appears this issue is, in fact, related to the multi-targeting of the frameworks. Please see my Edit #2 to the OP.

Comment: Good find. To be clear, what I outline in this answer is a prerequisite if you want to run on 2.1 Preview, since the runtime not there on the VM. But evidently there are additional things going on that you have identified.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer because it let me to discover the issue with the multi-framework issue.