# How can we publish the dynamically generated app service with our code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can we publish the dynamically generated app service with our code

In my code, am created web app service dynamically. By reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate

But actually the web service is published with blank data. we need to publish the app service with our code details dynamically while creating the app service. how can we do it?

Publish the same code for different users with different web app. When the user take his/her web(dynamically created) , it's not to be blank. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Publish the same code for different users with different web app. When the user take his/her web(dynamically created) , it's not to be blank. Is it possible?

When you publish a webapp, it has the only repo to store it. So it is hard to achieve publish same code with different webapp just in one publishment.

Also, the article byte provided is deploy a zip file to your webapp **which has generated as a blank before**. So I think what you want to achieve it impossible.

You could published with blank data first and deploy the code you want to the webapp using [curl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip) or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968029/azure-project-kudu-accepts-uploaded-zip-file-to-the-zipdeploy-endpoint-but-does).

**Update**:

> Deploy ZIP file with REST APIs

To deploy, send a **POST** request to `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy`. The [POST request](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) must contain the .zip file in the message body. The deployment credentials for your app are provided in the request by **using HTTP BASIC authentication**.

```
string userName = "$xxxx";
string userPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string webAppName = "xxxx";
var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{userName}:{userPassword}"));
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\xxx.zip");//zip path
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/zip");
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + "api/zipdeploy";
    var httpContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    var response2 = client.PostAsync(requestURl, httpContent).Result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How to call the Rest api?

Comment: What the features do you want to achieve?

Comment: Deploy ZIP file with REST APIs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip   but how to do this? any sample call

Comment: @Jinesh, I have update my reply, you could refer to it.

Comment: Great. It Worked for me. Its saved my lots of time.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

An option you could possibly explore is to use Kudu Zip Api for deploying your code/site once the app service is provisioned.

[Deploying from a zip file using Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file)