# Azure DevOps release pipeline: Angular and .NET Core application

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We're trying to release an Angular 7 / .NET Core application into Azure using the DevOps release pipelines. I have my build setup to create the .NET and Angular builds as separate artifacts which you can see in the screen shots below (under the Package or Folder box).

[image: Task1]
[image: Task2]

From what I've read it seems that you need to create two separate release tasks to deploy the builds to the web app. However the second build seems to be overriding the first which is causing the API not to start.

Does anyone know of a way to ensure the deployments in a given stage simply appends the changes rather than replacing them? Or is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to implement the following pattern for your pipeline:

1. 'ng build --prod' the angular app in it's own job, and add the artifacts to your pipeline
2. 'dotnet publish' the dotnet core api in it's own job, running in parallel with the angular job, and add the artifacts to your pipeline
3. Append the Angular and Dotnet Core artifacts together into a new artifact. This serves as your final package to deploy
4. Deploy the final package

You're missing step 3, so you'd want something like the following logic defined in YAML, where you create a new zip that represents your actual deployed bits in your pipeline. Then release that artifact, since it is the representation of what you have running on your instances.

> ```
>   - job: CreateReleaseArtifact
>     displayName: 'Package for shared-hosting of angular app and web api'
>     pool:
>       vmImage: windows-2019
>     dependsOn: 
>       - BuildNetcore
>       - BuildAngularApp
>     condition: succeeded()
>     steps:
>     - checkout: none
>     - download: current
>     - task: CopyFiles@2
>       displayName: 'Copy WebApi Files'
>       inputs:
>         SourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/api
>         Contents: '**/*'
>         TargetFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/package
>         includeRootFolder: false
>     - task: CopyFiles@2
>       displayName: 'Copy Angular Files'
>       inputs:
>         SourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/webapp
>         Contents: 'wwwroot/**'
>         TargetFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/package
>         includeRootFolder: true
>         OverWrite: true
>     - publish: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/package
>       artifact: package
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a way to ensure the deployments in a given stage simply appends the changes rather than replacing them?

Based on my experience, in your case, after deploy the API or Angular 7, then I you could use the [Kudu zip API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip) to upload another one to the Azure WebApp.

You could use the Powershell task to do that. For more inforamtion about powershell demo code, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968029/azure-project-kudu-accepts-uploaded-zip-file-to-the-zipdeploy-endpoint-but-does).

If creating another WebApp is acceptable, you could add a new WebApp and use the same service plan (**no extral** cost). Then you could deploy them separately.